# Google Chrome opens window underneath current window

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using Google Chrome on Ubuntu12.04. Whenever I go to the Chrome web store to install an extension, I think it opens a window right under the Chrome Window and I'm unable to access it. So, I cannot install any extension on Google Chrome in Ubuntu.

Anyone else has seen this? How do I check if there is a window under the browser window?

Answer (score 1):

If you have several windows open in google chrome you should see a small arrows next to the google chrome icon in the launcher.IN this example i have 2 windows open thus showing  2 arrows

[image: Showing 2 pages open]

To get a Quick view of all windows currently  open,  left click on the icon and you will see something like the below picture,which shows all current open windows.Click again to go back to original window or click on the window you wish to open. This also works for other programs for example having several gedit pages open.

[image]

If i go to google chrome settings/extensions/get extensions the chrome web store opens in another tab for me

Comment: That also happens when you use `Alt + \``? (Alt and the key above your tab) if you are looking for a shortcut

Comment: You care correct,the main difference being that `Alt + ` ` Shows a slightly different view being able to access all open windows from all open programs. Using the arrow keys to navigate the open windows . Is there a specific name for that function? So i could add that to the answer

Comment: no name that I know of. If you hold meta key to see the shortcuts, it is called "switch windows of current application"

Comment: Thanks but this does not work; please refer to my post below ...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the detailed answer; but it does not fix my problem. The Chrome browser seems to be creating a Dialog box under my browser window. And I cannot move the browser window to access it, since it is blocked for a response from the dialog box.

The Chrome icon on the Unity launcher does not show the multiple markers.
The short cut keys also do not get the Dialog box to the front.

BTW, I'm able to go to the Chrome web store; the problem happens when I click to add some extension.

(I'm using 12.04 in VirtualBox.)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I think that it is how Ubuntu works with browser. We have very similar problems with our applets in firefox and ubuntu. Very often it loads java dailog window and immediately hides it under a browser. It's very confusing for our users because application is blocked by modal window (JDialog) and it is hidden underneath. Only advanced user can see that in left edge of the screen there is another icon indicating that java dialog is open. I hope that there will be some fix to this issue some day.